# How to design an event receiver which is capable of showing the recent events

Tags: events, architecture, event-handling, pull

The home page of [meetup](http://www.meetup.com/) shows information on the recent meetups on the right hand side of the page. What kind of design patterns / tools (pref java based) would you use to implement such an output.

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of different approaches, which one you use would depend on several factors including the complexity of the business processes, the degree of flexibility desired and load.

**Simple Solution**

- "RSVP Updates" are written directly to some data source during the "RSVP" process; this process is essentially hard-coded.
- Have something that reads out the RSVP directly from the whatever data source / table they live in.
- This solution will be fine if the load and data volumes are excessive.  The key point is that the RSVP UI widget ends up pulling the data out of the same data source as where the updates are written to.

**Performance**

A few different options, based on the above as a starting point:

- Hold the data twice: once in the "master" (Transactional) table of RSVP data, and once in a table built for servicing the UI (Basically [OLTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OLTP) vs [OLAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OLAP)).  The second table would include all the relevant data so that there were no look-ups to other tables, and as it's an independent copy of the data you can manage it differently if you want to (for example: purge out old records so the table size is kept small).
- Or, instead of a second table just keep all the data in memory.  this would require you to pull the data out of the main transactional table whenever the in memory copy is lost.

**Flexibility**

- Same as the original approach but instead of hard-coding in the step that records the RSVP (into a single data source) use a more loosely-coupled approach so that you can add / change / remove as many event processors as you wish.  One will write the RSVP data to the main RSVP data source, while a second will do the same/similar but aggregated ready for the 
  "Recent RSVPs" UI Widget.
- Dependency Injection will give you the flexibility - certainly if you deal with a single implementation of the event handler.
- The Publish / Subscribe or Chain of Responsibility [patterns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_pattern_%28computer_science%29) might give you the basis of an approach.

Is that the kind of info you were after?